# How can I change the color of a set of rows of a QTableView?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QTableView` upon which I would like to change **dynamically** the background color of a set of rows. From what I could understand from previous posts, one (the ?) way to proceed is to use the `setData` method of `QAbstractTableModel` class. When trying this, the code runs but the background color does not change. Here is a snippet which reproduces the undesired behavior.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import pandas as pd


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            return str(value)

    def rowCount(self, index=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()

        data = pd.DataFrame([
            [1, 9, 2],
            [1, 0, -1],
            [3, 5, 2],
            [3, 3, 2],
            [5, 8, 9],
        ], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4', 'Row 5'])

        model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(model)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        # Here the example is for rows 1 and 2 but these values can change under the action of other widgets
        for r in range(1, 3):
            for c in range(0, model.columnCount()):
                model.setData(model.index(r, c), QtGui.QColor('red'), QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Would you know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You already have enough time to know that publishing the same question several times does not lead to anything productive, if you consider that the duplicate is not correct then just comment on it in this section, and thus the community will analyze whether the closure is correct or not. If you keep posting the same question then they will keep closing.

Comment: did it come to your mind that I did not how to proceed in such case ? Apparently not.

Comment: Obviously not, we are all susceptible to error, so SO allows us to talk and thus see if it is necessary to correct our actions.